# I can't edit my home page using elementor in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

whenever i try to edit my home page using elementor in wordpress. it says

```
The site is experiencing technical difficulties. 
Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

I contacted my host provider but they were unable to solve this issue They provided me with this code and said that the error is related to your woocommerce plugin I also deleted the plugin and installed it again but same case happened

```
[02-Aug-2019 07:28:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-quick-buy/includes/common-functions.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-quick-buy/includes/class-frontend.php(120): wc_qb_product_in_cart(269)
#1 /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-quick-buy/includes/class-quick-buy-auto-add.php(83): WooCommerce_Quick_Buy_FrontEnd->generate_button(Array)
#2 /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WooCommerce_Quick_Buy_Auto_Add->add_shop_quick_buy_button('')
#3 /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#4 /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php(65): do_action('woocommerce_aft...')
#6 /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(724): require('/home/hazaraxp/...')
#7 /home/ha in /home/hazaraxp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-quick-buy/includes/common-functions.php on line 50
```

Comment: once, you disable the woocomorce plugin from plugin folder.

Comment: please check once after disable plugin Quick Buy For WooCommerce.

Comment: The problem comes from outdated **Woocommerce quick buy** 3rd party plugin, but not from Woocommerce itself, so contact this plugin authors through their  support threads. StackOverFlow community don't handle any software support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem that do not set up properly or a plugin that wrongly modifies WordPress' internal object cache (which is basically a no-op). This could be configured by your host too.

Try disabling all plugins to see if this still happens.

Your Woo Sync error completely different though. You should ask about that in a separate thread if needed.

Thanks !!